# PyCharm: auto-insert Django template closing-tags ( {% endif %} {% endfor %} , etc. ) option?

Tags: django, pycharm

I've yet to find a setting that will enable auto-insertion of these closing tags, similar to how closing HTML tags are handled.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just hit tab after if

```
{% if<tab>
```

and you get

```
    {% if <cursor> %}

    {% endif %}
```

This works for many tags: `for`, `block`, `filter`, `spaceless`, `with`, but inexplicably not `blocktrans`, `autoescape`, and `comment` changes to `<comment></comment>`

Comment: Now (PyCharm 2020 at least) there is no need to type `{% if` - just type `if` and hit `<tab>` and it will auto-expand to `{% if <cursor> %} {% endif %}`